# obtener valor de variable antes de la funcion

Tags: funciones, variables

me llamo la atencion en jquery que accede al valor de la variable de la siguiente forma.

```
   variable.funcion();
```

y me preguntaba si saben de que forma se hace

```
 var p="hola";
 function prueba(){
   //aqui se ejecuta la variable
 }
 p.prueba();
```

como obtener el valor de la variable p de esa manera, si no es posible diganme.

Comment: Ummm ¿pero qué relación existe entre `p` y la función `prueba`?

Comment: como es posible relacionarlas de esa manera?

Comment: esa es mi duda.

Comment: si te refieres a la siguiente sintaxis `$('#elem').funcion()` esto es posible porque la función `$('#elem')` devuelve un objeto con x funciones que se pueden invocar. Necesitas usar objetos.

Comment: ¿pero es posible con javascript puro?